# Automatic id on tags

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, html-heading

Hello i'm building a side with a local scroller.
Is there any way i can take the value of my tag and use that as id.

```
<h2>test</h2>
```

so it would be like this

```
<h2 id="test">test</h2>
```

I'm running wordpress.

Comment: What happens when there are disallowed characters in the `h2` tags? Or duplicate texts? Why do you want to do this? Perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: The person i need to do this for cannot edit in html, so she cannot make an id.
So to make it easier i figured it would be a good solution.
The best solution would be if it could be in php.

Comment: Why do you need the ids in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('h2').each(function(){
   this.id = $(this).text();
});
```

But beware that [not all characters are allowed in an id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) :

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: You can use this.id = "id_" + $(this).text().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-]*/g, ''); to get IDs with a leading "id_" (to ensure the ID does not start with a number) and to remove all unallowed characters automatically.

Comment: Ah, [jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta#19492). Everything can be fixed with [jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif)